# maven npm exec-maven-plugin set registry and proxy

Tags: maven, npm, npm-install, exec-maven-plugin

Maven + npm install

I have following plugin to install package.json dependencies, is there a way i can run `npm config set registry` and `npm config set proxy` command with following plugin ?

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>exec-npm-install</id>
                  <phase>generate-sources</phase>

                  <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                  </goals>

                  <configuration>
                    <executable>npm</executable>
                    <arguments>
                      <argument>install</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
                  </configuration>

                </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was able to get it done through .nprmc file on project root

create file and have entry like

registry=
proxy=